# How to Implement `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` With Own Anchor Certificates in Swift?

Tags: swift, authentication, swift2, ssl-certificate

I would like to implement a client in Swift, using NSURLSession, which accesses a own company server using HTTPS. This server certificate is valid but signed by the company CA.

**how do I implement the `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` correctly in Swift?**

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert the CA certificate in DER format and add it as bundle resource to your project. In this example, this file is called `company_ca.der`.

Next you prepare an property with an array for the the CA certificates in your class:

```
private var anchorCertificates = NSMutableArray()
```

In the initialisation you load, convert and add the CA certificate:

```
let caCertData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("company_ca", withExtension: "der")!)!
let caCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, caCertData)!
anchorCertificates.addObject(caCert)
```

The delegate handler will look like this:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        var trust: SecTrustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        // Make sure we accept the given hostname/ip address for the certificate
        let serverHost = challenge.protectionSpace.host
        let sslPolicy = SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, serverHost)
        let sslPolicyArray = NSMutableArray()
        sslPolicyArray.addObject(sslPolicy)
        // Copy the existing certificates from the trust object
        let trustCertificateArray = NSMutableArray()
        let trustCertificateCount = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust)
        for i in 0..<trustCertificateCount {
            trustCertificateArray.addObject(SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, i)!)
        }
        // Replace the trust object
        var newTrust: SecTrustRef?
        if SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(trustCertificateArray, sslPolicyArray, &newTrust) != errSecSuccess {
            // application error
            completionHandler(.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }
        trust = newTrust!
        // Set our own anchor certificates to the trust.
        if SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, anchorCertificates) != errSecSuccess {
            // Application error.
            completionHandler(.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }
        // No keychains should be searched.
        if SecTrustSetKeychains(trust, []) != errSecSuccess {
            print("Failed to set no keychain for the trust.")
            completionHandler(.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }
        // Allow implicit anchors.
        if SecTrustSetOptions(trust, .ImplicitAnchors) != errSecSuccess {
            // Application error.
            completionHandler(.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }
        completionHandler(.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: trust))
    } else {
        // Handle any other case.
        completionHandler(.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    }
}
```